# compile and install python2.6.5-devel

Tags: python, compilation

I download python-2.6.5.tar.bz2 from http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.5/

Now I want to compile and install a python-2.6.5-devel version on my custom Linux OS, how can I do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there even a development version of 2.6 any more? I think all development is on 3.4 right now.

Comment: Well my custom Linux OS means my custom Linux OS other people gave me, actually I am not expert on Linux kernel, so this OS does not have other files as normal Linux, like yum, and even /usr/include.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart, I searched 'devel' in README File, but I don't see if 'configure with --enable-shared' means 'python2.6-devel' enabled?

Comment: I missed the devel part of your question, my apologies.  The header files are what the devel packages provide. Those are in the zip file as well. You just have to point your build system to the include directory.

Comment: It's fine, actually I'm installing distribute-0.6.28, but I got this  error: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)   I don't see pyconfig.h in the Include directoy in python's source code, that's why I'm suffering the devel stuff

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you [extract the .tar.bz2 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595285/how-to-install-tar-bz2-linux), you will surprisingly see a file inside with an all-caps named **`README`** ! It invites you to read it as sincerely as by naming itself! Oh Please, don't let it down. And then on the line 896, you will find it kindly says:

*To install the Python binary, library modules, shared library modules
(see below), include files, configuration files, and the manual page,
just type*

```
    make install
```

Comment: I'm not sure if if these include the 'devel' files? Thank you.